# Is it possible to specify variable-length constructor arguments when registering in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-container, ioc-container, params-keyword

I have an interface, `IFoo`, and three concrete classes: `FooA : IFoo`, `FooB : IFoo`, and `MultiFoo : IFoo`.

The constructor for `MultiFoo` looks like this:

```
public MultiFoo(params IFoo[] foos) { ... }
```

Can I specify particular resolution overrides when registering `MultiFoo` in Unity? I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IFoo, FooA>("Foo A");
container.RegisterType<IFoo, FooB>("Foo B");

container.RegisterType<IFoo, MultiFoo>(new ContainerControlledLifetime(),
    new ResolvedOverride<IFoo>("Foo A"),
    new ResolvedOverride<IFoo>("Foo B")
);
```

which would then pass a **resolved** FooA and a resolved FooB to the constructor at resolve-time:

```
new MultiFoo(new FooA(), new FooB())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`params` are compiler syntactic sugaring, you're really passing an array as a single parameter. To match that you'd configure the container like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IFoo, MultiFoo>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedArrayParameter<IFoo>(new ResolvedParameter<IFoo>("Foo A"), new ResolvedParameter<IFoo>("Foo B"))));
```

Resolver overrides are used at Resolve time, not at container setup time. The equivalent using resolve overrides would look like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IFoo, MultiFoo>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

var foo = container.Resolve<IFoo>(
    new ParameterOverride(
        "foos", 
        new ResolvedArrayParameter<IFoo>(new ResolvedParameter<IFoo>("Foo A"), new ResolvedParameter<IFoo>("Foo B"))));
```

Comment: That makes sense, I'd forgotten that you can pass an actual array to a params method call. I'm not sure about your second statement - previously I have used ResolvedParameter at register-time. I don't see the need to use one at resolve-time, because if it is being resolved right there then you can just call container.Resolve() and be done with it.

Comment: @AlexGill I took your statement about "resolution overrides" too literally to mean http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.resolveroverride(v=pandp.20).aspx. We're on the same page now.

Comment: Ah, my mistake - you're right, I did mean ResolvedParameter as opposed to a literal ResolvedOverride.